# I am a chemical element

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, imgur-maze

> ## [click.me.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEtVi.png)

---

Pretty simple, I know (^_^)

Comment: Is the answer Krypton? since its latin is hidden, and the answer is so well hidden as well... so am i the answer XD

Comment: @OmegaKrypton nope, the answer is not your username. Haha!

Answer (score 5):

Stuck at same point as Dorrulf.
Tried:

> Getting the Hex color for each of the five circles, then taking the component given by the key (Red Red Green ? Blue), converting to decimal and taking the corresponding letter of the alphabet with case matching the case in the key. Presumably '#' refers to a number, so the output will be three lowercase letters, a number and an uppercase letter
> #1642c6 => R = 16(hex) = 22(dec) = v
> #06b777 => R = 06(hex) = 06(dec) = f
> #ff0b6d => G = 0b(hex) = 11(dec) = k
> #000000 => 0 = ?
> #49a219 => B = 19(hex) = 25(dec) = Y
> (R:**22** - v, R:**06** - f, G:**11** - k, 0 - **?**, B:**25** - Y => `vfk?Y`).
> This could be another imgur link, but don't know what to put in ?. Tried 0, but that was a dead link

Comment: 1-F didn't do much either (for #/0).

Comment: On that regard, I get this [valid URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfkOY.png) but that's not part of the riddle, right?

Comment: Hahaha, that **has to be** a coincidence, because if thats a clue then I am truly stumped by it

Comment: My reasoning was that maybe the symbol is to be replaced by the answer to the riddle, so as the only valid URL matching an element name that could be it ... far fetched, I admit.

Comment: @Alexis purely coincidental.

Comment: You started on the right track, I will say that much.

Comment: I have an idea I'm working on, but I will have to wait till my lunch break to follow through on it

Comment: Sounds good, ping me when you update.

Comment: @WELZ is the key used on this part of the puzzle?

Comment: @Dorrulf yes, the key is used together with the ID.

Comment: Well, the color picker I used gave me vgk0Z instead, but that didn't amount to anything either. I guess I mean, I wonder if the values are off or if it's something else...

Comment: I played around with chemical elements, dates and a few other things but couldn't find anything significant that lined up with those numbers/letters

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> I've gotten to:
>  Key: RRG0B
>  And: [image: puzzle img]
>  No idea how to resolve it so far...
>  Ideas:
>  May resolve to an atomic weight value that would identify the element.

Shot in the dark answer:

> Last puzzle is 196 (mb 197), the atomic weight for gold, which is element Au. Au also happens to be the abbreviation for Adobe Audition.
>  Again, hopeful shot in the dark. Honestly not sure how to use the key to get that value.

---

Steps:

> 1. Follow the link. Image says to check the 'edit' view of the original post.
>  2. Scrolling all the way to the bottom reveals: [yes]: `kZ4yX`
>  3. Modify the original link from https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEtVi.png to https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ4yX.png
>  4. This is where we get the key value. Modify the link again using the id value to get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hynyf.png
>  5. You should now be at the image I reposted above, along with the Key value. Not sure what to do at this point.

Reasoning for my proposed answer:

> I looked at op's profile and discovered they have used adobe products for their answers before. Also, adobe products use icons that look similar to periodic table element values. I figured, based on the title and these things, that maybe the answer was both an element and a hint at some adobe software. My first guess was going to be Ai/Al for aluminium / illustrator (if lower case l = upper case i/I). But, I found Au to more directly fit two cases, and figured I'd make one guess.
>  Also, it kind of fit the puzzle image I was stuck on in that:
>  1. 3 values previous to a # could indicate a 3 digit number (which I attributed to the atomic weight of an element. Another reason I didn't go for aluminium).
>  2. The capital A at the end was the first letter of the elements I was looking at.
>  Again, big jump with little basis. But I was stuck, so I tried something.

Comment: Good start, another user may know how to use the key. `:D`

Comment: Do I need software to resolve it? rot13(vf vg Nh?)

Comment: Nope, sorry - that isn't it.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to this answer?

Comment: I hope my edits provide what you were looking for @GentlePurpleRain. I'm not super clear on what you were looking for but anticipate you're generally going for getting me to add clarification to a lot of what I posted.

Comment: @JamesOtter got started on the right track (what to do after your step 5).

Comment: That's great; thanks!  Reading the question and then your previous answer, it wasn't at all clear to me where the image came from.  It seemed like you were answering a different question altogether.  This makes it much clearer.

Comment: True and fair. Thank you for getting me to be less lazy and clean it up haha. Thanks @GentlePurpleRain

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers:

> R:22 - Ti 
> R:06 - C
> G:11 - Na
> 0 - ?
> B:25 - Mn
> It spells: Tin Can
> so Sn?

Comment: I like it but it does not make use of the capitalization nor the ordering of the last clue ... Also, if you try to do the reasoning backwards, this would have lead to different colors.

Comment: @Alexis, yeah true... just a wild guess :)